# Incremental grouping via regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression in Javascript that creates groups with incremental text but don't know if this can be done via regex.

I have the following string:

GALLUPER SUPERSTORE BAULKHAM HILL NSW AUSTRALIA

and what I'd like to build is a regular expression that matches/creates the following groups:

```
Group 1: AUSTRALIA
Group 2: NSW AUSTRALIA
Group 3: HILL NSW AUSTRALIA
Group 4: BAUKHAM HILL NSW AUSTRALIA
Group 5: SUPERSTORE BAUKHAM HILL NSW AUSTRALIA
```

So far I've been successful in matching/creating groups with one word using the regular expression:

```
/(?:\s(\w+))/gi
```

but that creates 5 groups with individual words:

```
Group 1: SUPERSTORE
Group 2: BAUKHAM
Group 3: HILL
Group 4: NSW
Group 5: AUSTRALIA
```

I can obviously use loops to do what I'd like to achieve but I'm wondering if a single regular expression can create the same output.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not is not a good regex idea. You may use something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/bxJrnk/1), but it is limited to the indicated number of groups.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for your answer, the problem is I don't know in advance the number of words the string will have so I need something different.

Comment: Yes, use somthing different from regex. Once you cme up with some code that does not work, please come back and share.

Comment: `(?:\s(\w+))` only creates a single group.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Javascript @melpomene

Answer (score 1):

Like Wiktor said, instead of doing it by regex you can write some code for it. Here is a javascript code for same. Try playing with it,

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function abc(s) {
      var tokens = s.split(" ");
      var ss = "";
      for (var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        for (var j = tokens.length - i; j < tokens.length; j++) {
          ss += tokens[j];
          if (j + 1 < tokens.length) {
            ss += " ";
          }
        }
        ss += "<br/>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ss;
    }
  </script>

  <body>

    <input type="text" id='intxt' value='GALLUPER SUPERSTORE BAULKHAM HILL NSW AUSTRALIA' size="100" />
    <button type="button" onclick="abc(document.getElementById('intxt').value)">Click here to see demo</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```